# working with tiled animated sprites in andEngine

Tags: java, android, eclipse, andengine

I am working with a relatively small sprite sheet that contains 1 row of 6 tiles. what I would like to do is loop through the first 5 tiles 3 times and then stop on tile 6. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is about a simple for-loop?

Comment: I'm using the animate method from AndEngine. I was able to get it to loop the proper amount of times through the correct subset of tiles. I just need to get it to stop on a specific tile that is not apart of the main subset for the loop.

Comment: @user3547741 
You can use below function for animation. In That you set no of loop and tiles.


sprite.animate(your FrameDurations in long[], your frame index int[], new pAnimationListener)

Comment: OK, I have it looping through the correct frames. I just need it to stop on a frame that is not part of the loop. Possible?